# How do I save the progress of a countdown timer?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, delegates

So I am building an app in swift that sets a long timer for different tasks. I would like to be able to save the progress of the timer so that a user could leave the view controller and come back to it later.

Users select a task from a tableView, each of which has an amount of time attached to it, and are segued to an actual timer. I would like for users to able to leave the timer and for the amount of time left to update in my data model.

What I have so far doesn't seem to be working, and I'm not sure what to do. This code below is for the user to leave the timer and return to the table. TaskData is my from my data model.

```
@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
    let item = TaskData()
    item.time = String(seconds)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    delegate?.viewController(self, didFinishEditing: item)
}
```

In my table view controller I use this function below

```
func viewController(_ controller: ViewController, didFinishEditing item: TaskData) {
    if let index = tasks.index(of: item) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            configureText(for: cell, with: item)
        }
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    saveTasklistItems()
}
```

When I go to the table view from the timer(ViewController) and then return to the timer, the time left in the timer reverts to what it was originally.

Here is the code for both view controllers

```
import UIKit

class TaskListViewController: UITableViewController, 
AddNewTaskViewControllerDelegate, TimerViewControllerDelegate {

var tasks: [TaskData]

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    tasks = [TaskData]()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    loadChecklistItems()
}


//DELEGATE PROTOCOLS
func addNewTaskViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: AddNewTaskViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func addNewTaskViewController(_ controller: AddNewTaskViewController, didFinishAdding item: TaskData) {
    let newRowIndex = tasks.count
    tasks.append(item)
    print(item.time)

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: newRowIndex, section: 0)
    let indexPaths = [indexPath]
    tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    saveTasklistItems()
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "AddTask" {
        let navigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! AddNewTaskViewController
        controller.delegate = self
    } else if segue.identifier == "ShowTimer" {
        let navigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! ViewController
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell) {
            controller.timerTask = tasks[indexPath.row]
            controller.timerTime = tasks[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}

func viewController(_ controller: ViewController, didFinishEditing item: TaskData) {
    if let index = tasks.index(of: item) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            configureText(for: cell, with: item)
        }
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    saveTasklistItems()
}
///////////////////////////////

func configureText(for cell: UITableViewCell, with item: TaskData) {
    let label = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    label.text = item.time
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    let indexPaths = [indexPath]
    tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
    saveTasklistItems()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tasks.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskListItem", for: indexPath)

    let taskItem = tasks[indexPath.row]
    let label = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    label.text = taskItem.task
    label2.text = taskItem.time
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}

//SAVE FUNCTIONALITY
func documentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}
func dataFilePath() -> URL {
    return documentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Tasklists.plist")
}
func saveTasklistItems() {
    let data = NSMutableData()
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: data)
    archiver.encode(tasks, forKey: "TasklistItems")
    archiver.finishEncoding()
    data.write(to: dataFilePath(), atomically: true)
}

func loadChecklistItems() {
    let path = dataFilePath()
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: path) {
        let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: data)
        tasks = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "TasklistItems") as! [TaskData]
        unarchiver.finishDecoding()
    }
}
}
```

Above is the tableView, and below i'll post the timer

```
import UIKit

protocol TimerViewControllerDelegate: class {
func viewController(_ controller: ViewController, didFinishEditing item: TaskData)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var timerTaskName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timerTimeSetting: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

weak var delegate: TimerViewControllerDelegate?

var timerTask: TaskData?
var timerTime: TaskData?
var seconds: Int = 0
var timer = Timer()
var isTimerRunning = false
var resumeTapped = false
var progressViewSpeed: Double = 0.0

//THIS BUTTON CREATS AN UPDATED TASK DATA TIME MEMBER
@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
    let item = TaskData()
    item.time = String(seconds)
    print(item.time)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    delegate?.viewController(self, didFinishEditing: item)
}
/////////////////////////////


@IBAction func startButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    if isTimerRunning == false {
        runTimer()
        self.startButton.isEnabled = false
    }
    if seconds >= (500 * 60 * 60) {
        seconds = (500 * 60 * 60)
    }
}

func runTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    isTimerRunning = true
    pauseButton.isEnabled = true
}

@IBAction func pauseButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if self.resumeTapped == false {
        timer.invalidate()
        self.resumeTapped = true
        self.pauseButton.setTitle("Resume",for: .normal)
    } else {
        runTimer()
        self.resumeTapped = false
        self.pauseButton.setTitle("Pause",for: .normal)
    }
}

/*
@IBAction func resetButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    timer.invalidate()
    seconds = 60
    self.timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
    if self.resumeTapped == true {
        self.resumeTapped = false
        self.pauseButton.setTitle("Pause",for: .normal)
    }
    isTimerRunning = false
    pauseButton.isEnabled = false
    startButton.isEnabled = true
}
*/

func updateTimer() {
    if seconds < 1 {
        timer.invalidate()
        //Send alert to indicate "time's up!"
    } else {
        seconds -= 1
        timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
    }
    progressViewSpeed = 1 / Double(seconds)
    progressView.progress += Float(progressViewSpeed)
}

func timeString(time:TimeInterval) -> String {
    let hours = Int(time) / 3600
    let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(time) % 60
    return String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pauseButton.isEnabled = false

    if let task = timerTask {
        timerTaskName.text = task.task
    }

    if let timerTimeLeft = timerTime {
        timerTimeSetting.text = timerTimeLeft.time
    }

    //I SOLVED A SERIOUS ERROR HERE
    let timeLeft: Int? = Int(timerTimeSetting.text!)
    seconds = Int(timeLeft!) * 60 * 60
    self.timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
    ///////////////////////////////

    self.progressView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2).scaledBy(x: 1, y: 150)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start your timer, save the current date as a time interval into an instance variable:

Define the instance variable:

```
var startTime: TimeInterval = 0.0
var elapseTime: TimeInterval = 0.0
let totalTime = 100.0 //Replace with your desired total time

weak var timer: Timer?
```

Then you might use code like this:

```
@IBAction func startButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
  //save the current date as a time interval
  startTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
  timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, 
    target: self, 
    selector: #selector(ViewController.updateTimer), 
    userInfo: nil, 
    repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func pauseTimer(_ sender: Any) {
   timer.invalidate()
   //Calculate the amount of time that's passed since starting the timer
   elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime

   //Calculate the amount of time remaining
   timeRemaining = totalTime - elapsedTime
   //Save timeRemaining to UserDefaults or do whatever you desire with it.
}
```

That is a very rough outline. You'll need to work out the details, but that should get you started.

Comment: I've implemented this and it's helpful, but my concern right now is for the remaining time to not change when a user segues back to the table view, so that the user can start from where they left off. This what i'm trying to do with my cancel button function. To give some context, You choose a name of a task and the number of hours you want to work on it, so the time left should persist when the user exits the time within the app or closes the app altogether.

Comment: Ok... The code above outlines how to calculate the time remaining. Save that value to userDefaults, and read it back on app launch. What part don't you understand?

Comment: Well I need to learn how to save things to userDefaults, I've only used NSkeyedArchiver so far

Answer (score 0):

Save an array of TaskData and their corresponding start times and/or end times and save that array to UserDefaults

Comment: How would I implement this?